# RabbitMQ as mqtt broker

Tags: java, rabbitmq, connection, mqtt, paho

I am trying to connect eclipse paho java client to rabbitmq-mqtt broker. For that I created one user mqtt-publisher-client but when I am trying to connect it is showing an error that "Broker unavailable (3)".

```
MqttClient client=new MqttClient("tcp://0000.0000.0000.0000:1883","mqtt-publisher-client123",new MemoryPersistence());
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setCleanSession(false);
options.setUserName("mqtt-publisher-client");
options.setPassword("publisher".toCharArray());
client.connect(options);
```

I want to Connect with mqtt-broker and publish messages. But it is not connecting. Rabbitmq is on linux and I am writing code in windows.

Comment: You probably want to include details of how you have configured RabbitMQ in the question

Answer (score 0):

`0000.0000.0000.0000` is not a valid IPv6 address.

Did you mean `tcp://0.0.0.0:1883`?  This is a way to say, connect to any local IP address on port 1883.

Replace `tcp://0000.0000.0000.0000:1883` with a valid address where the RabbitMQ broker is listening.

There is an [IPv6 address validator here](https://www.linkwebbie.com/apps/index/ipv6-validator/) to check.